# How can I have numpad always writing numbers by default and arrows with AltGr regardless of NumLock state in GNOME?

Tags: linux, gnome, keyboard-layout, wayland, xkb

I want to set the numpad so it by always writes digits regardless of the state of NumLock, but it writes arrows and math operators with AltGr.

In GNOME, I can set some options for the keyboard layout in Tweaks at *Mouse and keyboard → Additional layout options*. I am interested in these:

- *Compatibility options → Numeric keypad always enters digits (as in macOS)*, corresponding to the XKB option *numpad:mac*
- *Layout of numeric keypad → Unicode arrows and math operators*, corresponding to the XKB option *keypad:oss*

Each of these options alone does a part of what I want, but, if they are enabled together, the first option (numpad:mac) does not work, so the numpad's functions again depend on the state of NumLock, which I would like to avoid.

How can I set the numpad to do that? I use GNOME with Wayland, so things like *localectl* and *setxkbmap* do not work (except in X11 apps), but I expect that the results through them would be the same as described above because the keyboard settings in GNOME follow exactly the XKB settings. I am willing to edit XKB layout files because I already use a custom layout anyway, but I do not know how to do that there.

I use Arch Linux with GNOME 44 on Wayland.